# Why do I get "Permission denied" when redirecting the output of sudo echo "xyz" to a file?

Tags: permissions, sudo, io-redirection

Why do I get

```
-bash: test: Permission denied
```

when I run

```
sudo echo "xyz" > test
```

The directory permissions are:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2014-08-05 16:26
```

I have no problem creating a file in the directory using `sudo`.  But why can't I sudo echo into it?

Answer (score 17):

This happens because you're only running the `echo` command as root. The output redirection is handled by your (non-root) shell. To avoid this, don't use the shell's redirect and use an actual command to handle the writing: `tee`. What you want to do can be done as so:

```
echo "xyz" | sudo tee test > /dev/null
```

(if you don't redirect the output, `tee` will output `xyz` to stdout, too)