# Permission denied when saving iptable rules in Debian 8

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I want to open port 443 in my Debian 8 server but i get permission denied error.

my rules.v4 file looks like:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Feb 15 14:42:03 2017
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [208710:151335680]
-A INPUT -p icmp -m comment --comment "000 accept all icmp" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -m comment --comment "001 accept all to lo interface" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m comment --comment "002 accept related established rules" -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -m comment --comment "099 allow ssh access" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m comment --comment "100 allow http and https access" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 1122 -m comment --comment "150 allow phpmyadmin access" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m comment --comment "999 drop all" -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Feb 15 14:42:03 2017
```

After making the changes in `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` i tried to save with

```
sudo iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

I get error message `-bash: /etc/iptables/rules.v4: Permission denied`

I tried with `sudo bash -C "iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4"` i get `no such file or directory` when the file exists.

I also tried with `tee`

```
sudo tee iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

and

```
sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4"
```

when i do `netstat -tulnp | grep 443` i get no output.

Comment: It looks to me that there is no `/etc/iptables/` directory. Check that first and move further.

Comment: `/etc/iptables` does exist... i have `rules.v4` and `rules.v6` files inside

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148592/why-do-i-get-permission-denied-when-redirecting-the-output-of-sudo-echo-xyz/148596#148596

Answer (score 14):

There are 2 permissions involved in this operation:

1. permission to read `iptables-save`
2. permission to write to  `/etc/iptables/rules.v4`

You cannot use sudo on the second permission needed.

The last command you posted should work, just change `-C` to `-c`, otherwise drop to root shell with

```
sudo su -
```

Comment: okay, I am now working with root privileges... But still the port is not open

Comment: How do you determine that the port is not open? Do you have a webserver with ssl active? did you check with `netstat`?

Comment: yes i have ssl active and i did check with `netstat -tulnp | grep 443`

Comment: I can't find -u in the manual of my netstat, it is a flag I never use. Also, what do you mean by ssl active? Apache with a virtualhost listening on port 443?

Comment: -u checks for UDP [look here](http://netstat.net/) yes apache with listening on port 443

Answer (score 4):

You're using `tee` incorrectly. The `iptables-save` command creates the contents of what *should* be saved and sends it to stdout. The `tee` command needs to read the stdout of `iptables-save` and write it to the designated file.

The correct way to save the routes without needing to use root shell is to have `iptables-save` pipe the content to `tee` which will then save the stdout to file.

`sudo iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/iptables/rules.v4`

Comment: @berndbausch - You must be mixing up OP's question with something else. Their title specifically says "saving iptable rules". Then they go on to say "I also tried with tee". You should re-read the question and consider removing your comment.

Comment: Indeed, `tee` appears in the question, and I managed to overlook it. Upon re-reading the whole question, it is at least ambiguous to me. The last remark "when i do netstat -tulnp | grep 443 i get no output." indicates that OP wanted to put in place new rules, which requires `iptables-restore`, but the rest of the question seems to be a tangle of confusion. Nothing we can do with a four years old question. You feedback has validity, and I will indeed remove my comment. Sorry.

Comment: @berndbausch - No problem. I've misread posts before and even continued to misread them after someone pointed out my error. I reread this one 5 times to make sure I wasn't doing that again. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

I´ve had same problem, which I solved:

1. Change group to user on rules.v4

   ```
   sudo chgrp "usergroup" /etc/iptables/rules.v*
   ```
2. Enable writting permission to group

   ```
   sudo chmod 664 /etc/iptables/rules.v*
   ```
3. Try again

   ```
   sudo iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
   ```

This worked for me, I hope it helps.