# SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/abrtd from create access on the lnk_file .lock

Tags: centos, selinux

I am getting this error on my **CentOS 7** desktop. Following is the detailed log.

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/abrtd from create access on the lnk_file .lock.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that abrtd should be allowed create access on the .lock lnk_file by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'abrtd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-abrtd
# semodule -i my-abrtd.pp

Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:abrt_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
Target Context                system_u:object_r:var_spool_t:s0
Target Objects                .lock [ lnk_file ]
Source                        abrtd
Source Path                   /usr/sbin/abrtd
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          bilesh.intra.2pirad.com
Source RPM Packages           abrt-dbus-2.1.11-48.el7.centos.x86_64
Target RPM Packages           
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.13.1-166.el7_4.7.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Enforcing
Host Name                     bilesh.intra.2pirad.com
Platform                      Linux bilesh.intra.2pirad.com
                              3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jan 25
                              20:13:58 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   249
First Seen                    2018-02-05 10:18:25 IST
Last Seen                     2018-03-09 10:57:07 IST
Local ID                      912e2a18-e121-4ff5-b14f-13862b277958

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1520573227.768:410): avc:  denied  { create } for  pid=4784 comm="abrt-dbus" name=".lock" scontext=system_u:system_r:abrt_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:var_spool_t:s0 tclass=lnk_file


type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1520573227.768:410): arch=x86_64 syscall=symlinkat success=no exit=EACCES a0=7ffd63ccc850 a1=6 a2=7fe935f0a9d2 a3=0 items=0 ppid=1 pid=4784 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm=abrt-dbus exe=/usr/sbin/abrt-dbus subj=system_u:system_r:abrt_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)

Hash: abrtd,abrt_t,var_spool_t,lnk_file,create
```

As suggested, I tried executing the following command but it also didn't work.

```
sudo ausearch -c 'abrtd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-abrtd
```

returns the following error

```
could not write output file: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'my-abrtd.te'
```

I'm in need of guidance.

---

**Update #1**

As pointed out by garethTheRed, the piped command doesn't have permission.

> You are running `ausearch` as root with sudo, but you are piping that to
>   `audit2allow` which won't be running as root. That tries to write to the
>   current directory as your regular user, who doesn't have write access to it.

Following are the commands I ran.

```
$ sudo ausearch -c 'abrtd' --raw | sudo audit2allow -M my-abrtd
$ sudo semodule -i my-abrtd.pp
```

But this didn't solve the issue. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148592/why-do-i-get-permission-denied-when-redirecting-the-output-of-sudo-echo-xyz .  You are running `ausearch` as root with sudo, but you are piping that to `audit2allow` which won't be running as root.  That tries to write to the current directory as your regular user, who doesn't have write access to it.

Comment: garethTheRed - Thanks for pointing that out, I understood but even after successfully running it, I'm getting the same error.

Comment: You might have incorrect SELinux file label applied for `/var/run/abrt/` (where abrtd tries to create `.lock` file). You can check the security labels using `ls -Zd /var/run/abrt` and apply the default contexts using `restorecon`. If this helps, I can write a more detailed answer.

Comment: sebasth - I ran `ls -Zd /var/run/abrt` and this is what I get as a response `drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:abrt_var_run_t:s0 /var/run/abrt`. Not sure what to make of it.

Comment: The target security context has label of `var_spool_t`, might be worthwhile to check the security labels in `/var/spool/` as well. The default policy labels are documented in [*abrt_selinux*](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-abrt_selinux/) manpage, and should be the ones applied by `restorecon`.

Comment: sebasth - I ran the command `ls -Zd /var/spool` which yielded `drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:var_spool_t:s0 /var/spool`. So, the label is `var_spool_t` it seems, right?